# Parallel promise chain with sequential dynamic content in between

Tags: javascript, dynamic, promise, bluebird, sequential

I can't get my head around this problem how dynamic results can be added to a promise chain, i've looked everywhere if this is even possible. Hope someone can clarify or give me a good solution for the following example i'm trying to accomplish (it's a small music player):

```
// API requests are done with a promise
let pfetch = (url) => Promise.resolve( $.ajax(...) )

// This will give me all playlists from a user
pfetch( 'USER-API-URL' )

    // The playlists i get have tracklists
    .then( results =>

        // When all playlists are fetched continue (Promise.all = parallel)
        Promise.all( results.playlists.map( playlist => pfetch(playlist.url) ) )
    )

    // Results of all playlists in arguments
    .then( playlists => 

        // Each playlist has tracks and next_url
        playlists.map( playlist => {

        /* playlist.tracks 
         * if (playlist.next_url) pfetch(playlist.next_url)
         * append results to playlist.tracks
         */

        })
    )

        //only continue if all all tracks are complete

    //can i do a Promise.join() in the previous step?
    .then( () => console.log('finished,yay!') )
```

Some of the track lists have a `next_url` in their response, meaning, i should also fetch the next url belonging to the track list, so i can get a complete `tracklist.tracks`. However this has to be sequential as i don't know if there is a subsequent `next_url` in the response. When there is no `next_url` i'm finished with one track list and can do the same with the next (hence `.map`).

**So my question**, how do you do this dynamic content chaining in promises? I know you can do sequencing with `reduce`, but in this case the amount of `next_url`'s is not fixed. I've thought about recursion and yet to find a good example for `Promise.each`.

Thumbs up in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a function to recursively deal with a playlist url

```
var getPlaylistUrl = url => 
    pfetch(url).then(playlist => 
        playlist.next_url ? Promise.all([].concat.apply([playlist.tracks], getPlaylistUrl(playlist.next_url))) : playlist.tracks
    );
```

you should be able to rewrite your code as follows

```
pfetch('USER-API-URL')
.then(results => Promise.all(results.playlists.map(playlist => getPlaylistUrl(playlist.url))))
.then( playlists => {
    // playlists should be complete
})
.then( () => console.log('finished,yay!') );
```

Comment: well. this kind of solves the problem but is there a more elegant workaround or is a recursive function the only way?

Comment: the data is recursive in nature, you need to "recurs" through it :p. What do you mean it "kind of solves the problem" - does it give you the result you require or not?

Comment: yeah but in `{results: [result.tracks,[result.tracks,[result.tracks,...]]]]}` will need to flatten it, but indeed your solution is in my list of todos for accepting answers. Just one more question, if you don't mind. If i have data in the second `.then(...)` promise, is there a way to tell the first `.then(...)` about the results or does a promise not allow this? I'm still hoping for this 'beautiful' way of doing it (perfectionist speaking ;)).

Comment: Well. What's holding me back to just test it. nvm... accepted.

Comment: I just changed one line, I think that'll solve the "nesting" in the result